# CakePHP with Azure Blob

Tags: file, cakephp, azure, upload

I was wondering if anyone came across a good turtorial on how to upload file to Azure using cakephp 2.* ?? even if someone can point me to the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!! .... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most of the rapid development framework package in any language you will get base  functionalities in the package however you would need to write or include components which are specific to your need and same goes with CakePHP. To access Azure Blob Storage with CakePHP, you can create a DataSource by taking the code from Windows Azure PHP SDK and then use in your package to meet your need.

About user1679844, question to use cpanel server with Azure Blob storage, I am not sure what could be the problem. Once you have the data source build as class I think you sure can use the same Data source.

I can provide some guidance on how you can get PHP libraries to Azure Blob storage locally and then you can create a data source using the source code and include in your framework and release for others to use.

You can download PHP SDK for Windows Azure Blob Storage from [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/common-tasks/download-php-sdk/) and the following link provides step by step details on how to access Windows Azure Blob using the PHP SDK

- [Accessing Azure Blob Storage in PHP](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/blob-service/)

There is [another older PHP codebase](http://www.windowsazure4e.org/learn/labs/lab2_azure_storage/lab2_1_azure_storage_blobs/#part2) is available to access Azure Storage with PHP which you can take a look.

Here is a [sample PHP Data source for Windows Azure Tables](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Howard/2010/02/02/microsoft-windows-azure-tables-datasource) is available which you can take a look as well. If you happen to start working on create a data source for Azure Blob I sure can add soe help.

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP itself does not come up with upload specific code. It is up to you to implement the required code and APIs for the Azure service.

Azure is using [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179355.aspx

So maybe better look (Google) for a generic file upload tutorial and a RESTful tutorial. Also there is a [php SDK for Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/).